# Treatment vs Management

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between management and treatment? 
Is the word "treatment" just a medical term or can we use it in another situations? i.e in order to say "I want to relieve his sadness " can I use treat instead of relieve ?

Comment: The dictionary definitions don't answer this sufficiently?

Comment: The problem is, you can't *treat* an emotion (sadness), but you can treat a medical condition.

Comment: There's too many variables in this question, can you be more specific please? Do you want to help a friend's sadness by offering him friendship and support, or are you a professional who can offer medication, counselling etc?

Answer (score 2):

Treatment aims to alleviate/ reduce/ remove a (medical) condition.

Management is essentially keeping the condition in control. In a broader sense, it can be an overall strategy, including  treatment, pre- and post- treatment aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Treatment is therapy. Management is the plan to treat patient.

Answer (score 0):

Accountants talk about the way a particular transaction has been ***treated*** in the books and accounts.

For example a decision as to whether to capitalise a large item of expenditure, or whether to write it off against the profit/loss for the period under report, depends on what ***treatment*** is deemed appropriate.

A large company's financial management, usually in consultation with their auditors, will have a set of laid-down policies regarding accounting ***treatment*** on a complete range of issues, e.g. policy on sales revenue recognition, accounting for and methods of pricing stocks (inventories), depreciation of fixed assets etc.

The first meaning of the verb ***treat*** in my dictionary says *behave towards or deal with in a certain way*. hence I see no reason why ***treatment*** should not be used in all kinds of fields.

Answer (score 0):

A city's waste/garbage treatment - The city's processing waste or garbage.

A city's waste/garbage management - The city's management of garbage generation and treatment, which includes educating residents to reduce garbage, encouragement to recycle, managing of recycling facilities, monetizing recyclables, garbage collection scheduling, transforming garbage to reusable or monetizable commodities.

Similarly, water treatment vs water management.

Treatment - processing the water to ensure the quality of water flowing off the taps/faucets.

Management - includes treatment, procuring water sources and resources, joining a water treatment cooperative and executing the contracts of the cooperative, retaining legal representation to pursue legal actions against individual, state, federal or upstream jurisdictions whose activities might impede the availability of water resources, public education on water usage.

Cancer treatment - Use of medical procedures, therapy or medicine to remove, cure, reduce a cancer, or else reduce its impact.

Cancer management - holistic approach towards cancer, which includes treating the cancer, change in lifestyle that would either help the fight against the cancer or otherwise alleviate the hardships involved, pain management, maximizing quality of life, psychological therapy against depression due to suffering cancer and its treatment, dietary management to ensure the body is sufficiently healthy to accept the effects and treatment of the cancer, education for the patient, physical and mental exercise regimen, preparing a living will and hospice, mental and attitude preparation of patient, friends and relatives.

In manufacturing:

Scrap/rejects treatment - processing, recycling or disposal of items or remnants that were rejected from the manufacturing processes.

Scrap/rejects management - includes treatment as well as plans and actions to improve processes to reduce the rate of rejects, change of material vendors, finding/maintaining a market for low quality products that might otherwise be rejects, retaining legal representation to allow a company to dispose scrap in a cost effective way that might present hazards to the public, but satisfying regulations and loop-holes.

Comment: What I wrote is true, so why the down-vote?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, either.

Answer (score -3):

treatment is the condition in which something is treated in medical codition ;"matlab kishi chej ko thek krna under medical condition"
Managment means to manage the uncontrolled cond. Or harsh condition "matlab kisi chej ko aur jada kharb hone se bachana or us chej ko vahi manage kar lena"
Without going any medical condition: ex - seawage!

Comment: comment on the answer